# How to center the content of all the Sharepoint Gallery cards?

Tags: sharepoint-online

How can I center the content of all the SharePoint Gallery cards?

[image: screenshot]

Gr. P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Follow my answer given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/308834/hide-the-checkboxes-of-every-card-of-a-sharepoint-list-in-gallery-view) up to step #4 to enter into advanced mode in gallery view formatting.
2. Then add below styling to top/outer most `div` element in the JSON:

```
"style":{
    "text-align": "center"
},
```

**Output**:

[image]

If any column value is not aligned to center automatically, locate the code used in same JSON for that particular column and then add `"text-align": "center"` styling to nested elements wherever required.